# Apache vhost catch all

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I'm having an issue with Apache (2.2) on Windows.

I basically have 2 Wordpress projects. 1 of them runs on 1 (sub)domain (sub1.mydomain.com) and 1 on another (sub2.mydomain.com).

The first one just uses that (sub) domain, but the other project hosts thousands of sites using domain mapping and thus must be a catch-all on the domain.

I have currently set the vhosts up for the 2 'sites', with 1 of them having 'serveralias *':

```
# The catchall project
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/webroot1"
  ServerName sub2.domain.com
  ServerAlias *
</VirtualHost>

# The single project
<VirtualHost sub1.domain.com:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/webroot2"
  ServerName sub1.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried changing the order of them, but that changed nothing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the ***default*** for a vhost :

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default